# Sharepoint 2013 - open a second modal window from a first modal window

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, client-object-model, modal-dialog

I have an aspx page opened in a modal. On button click I need to close the current modal and open a new one or just open the new page in the same modal.

Any suggestions?

Below is my code:

```
function updateListItem(id,val) {

    var clientContext = args['context'];
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Weekly');

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);

    oListItem.set_item('SortOrder', val);

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.succeed), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));

}

function succeed() {

    window.frameElement.cancelPopUp(); 
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 500;
    options.height = 250;
    options.url = dialogResult;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
}
```

But it gives me this error:

> SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script

Comment: There seems to be a couple of possible reasons for this. Take a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script

Answer (score 1):

The best way to open a modal dialog in SharePoint 2013 is to use the built-in JavaScript function called "[**OpenPopUpPage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410825(v=office.14).aspx)". This was introduced in SP2010 and is used widely throughout SP2013.

To change the page being loaded within the modal dialog, you can then use a simple "window.location.href" function.

EXAMPLES:

**Opening a Modal Dialog**

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/Site/Lists/Weekly/Sorted.aspx', 'Weekly', 500, 250);">Open Dialog</a>
```

**Changing What's in the Dialog**

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.href('/Site/Lists/Weekly/Details.aspx');">View Details</a>
```